# angular translate - use two language at same time

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I have created multilingual site using angular-translate. Its working awesome but i have new requirement according to which i want 2 language on same page at a time.

Actually my website allows user to create custom forms in any language.So suppose that user currently viewing site in Arabic but if his creating form for lets say English then using

```
$translate.use('en')
```

will change whole site and form builder in english but i want only form builder to be in english but container which was in arabic will also get translated in english.

anybody have any idea about how to achieve this?

Comment: $translate.use('en') is going to change application configuration. I am wondering you want to set two languages at the same time which angular translate does not support.

Comment: I know angular translate support only one language but i'm asking about if there is any work around or any other solution??

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51720981/6270421) approach would help you use translation functionality how ever you want. you just need to change it as follows.

`<strong>{{'hello' | language: 'en'}}{{'world' | language: 'ch'}}</strong>`