# Angular 4 switch LTR to RTL based on languages

Tags: angular

I am working on an Angular 4 project and using Arabic and English language, so I want to switch template from LTR to RTL based on language.
I use a bootstrap, how to handle rtl.css files?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Angular CDK bidirectionnal](https://material.angular.io/cdk/bidi/overview) library to help you with bidirectionnality. The official Material Angular library use it.

Comment: I use a bootstrap, how to handle rtl.css files?

Comment: The Angular CDK is not link to any theme. You can use a css class in your rtl.css file that handle rtl case, and add this class dynamically with the help of the CDK.

Comment: I cannot understand this, if you have a simple example please share it

Answer (score -2):

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51720981/6270421)

you just need to use the css text-align property to LTR and RTL based on the selected language

```
<div ng-class="lang.selectedLanguage === 'en' ? 'left-text' : 'right-text'">
```

or create a directive which you can use on all text elements that will fulfill the above requirement